# Android kernel printk() and clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME) time reversal of 60ms

Tags: android, linux-kernel, printk

I need to measure Android kernel and framework processing time for mouse HID event.

- USB mouse device side, I use Arduino Micro with HID mouse sample.
  It send HID event every 10ms.
- Linux Kernel, I put `printk()` on
  `hid_irq_in()`, `hid_input_report()` in hid-core.c
- Android framework, I add logcat with
  `clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME)` on InputReader::process.
- Android sample App, I put
  `Log.d() elapsedRealtimeNanos()` on View.OnTouchListener

Problem: App side onTouchListner time is 60ms earlier than kernel `hid_irq_in()`. kernel IRQ should be 1-2ms before onTouchListener.

I am not sure why time is reverted. If I use not accurate way to get time, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

"dmesg" add timestamp of `printk()` message. But that time is not synced with `clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME)` in userland.

I need to call `ktime_get_boottime()` then `printk()` in kernel code. That time is synced with `clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME)` in userland.

With this measurement, I found handling mouse left click event takes 3ms in kernel and framework.